# `rest*` vs `rest @ _*` when pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, scala-3

```
val List(a, b, c, rest*) = ...

val List(a, b, c, rest @ _*) = ...
```

Both seem to work, but I've had situations where the former raises the error "bad simple pattern". Only occasionally though.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difference between Scala 2 and Scala 3 syntax. Just Scala 2 syntax is still working so far in Scala 3

Scala 2:

```
val List(a, b, c, rest @ _*) = ...
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SJbD2tTBQgiI4kF6Lun1rQ

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lCVAKK2WTlG99n6bBh4Tcw

Scala 3:

```
val List(a, b, c, rest*) = ...
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rV7UCBDaRzWyXLFNeRxxsg

Docs:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/vararg-splices.html

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/vararg-splices.html